# VBA: Get data from HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba

The objetive is to extract the XBT/USD value from this website: https://www.bitmex.com/ I got this code from another question and tried to edit it for the need but it returns the QTUMU17 value.

```
Option Explicit

Sub BitMEX_BTC_USD()

     'Open website
        Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.Navigate "https://www.bitmex.com/"
        Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Loop

    'Extract USD value
        Dim kfc As String
        Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

            For Each oHTML_Element In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
                If oHTML_Element.className = "PlusTick" Then
                    kfc = oHTML_Element.innerText
                End If
            Next

    'Value
        Debug.Print kfc

    End Sub
```

HTML code according to inspect element:

```
<i class="price">2765.3</i>
```

Thanks in advance for your valuable help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be focusing on class names here. Each currency is under `ticker-item` class. `XBT/USD` is the first currency so you should go for (0):

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("ticker-item")(0).innerText
```

Since you want to extract just the price, you need to dig into that. `price` element is the first occurrence again so you need to get the `price` with (0):

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("ticker-item")(0).getElementsByClassName("price")(0).innerText
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems. Your For each statement is searching through every classname that is equal "PlusTick" and the last statement that meets this criteria on the website happens to be the QTUMU17 value. The other problem I see is that if you search by the class name PlusTick you will only pick up the value if it was a "PlusTick" but from looking at the website it appears there will be instances in which your XBT/USD could be a minus tick. I'm not very experienced in html but I hope this helps you further understand your current output.